# find . -exec echo {} \; = missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: bash, find

Why doesn't this work? (echo is not the real command)

```
$ find . -type d -exec echo {} \;
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I managed to do that anyway like this:

```
$ for f in `find . -type d`; do echo $f; done
```

Comment: Works fine here. Did you remember to escape the ; when you actually ran it?

Comment: You need to specify the "real command"

Comment: It works fine with me. Try to use `xargs` : `find . -type d | xargs ls`

Comment: Does the real command resolve to an actual binary (in `/bin`, `/usr/bin` or somewhere else in your `PATH`), or are you trying to use a shell builtin or function as the command? The first argument to `-exec` needs to be an actual executable binary or script.

Comment: @Pascal: Does this only happen when you try with the *real command* or does it *also* happen when you try it with `echo`? That should help you figure whether or not the *real command* is the culprit. It probably is.

Comment: This question really isn't answerable unless you provide either the "real" command, or a command that produces the same behavior.

Comment: FYI -- the thing you ended up doing is actually buggy -- any filenames with spaces in them will have the parts before and after the space treated as two separate files.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions

Comment: @Sp.: `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`

Answer (score 7):

This work for me.

```
find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;
```

Braces are enclosed in single quote marks to protect them from interpretation  as  shell  script  punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is from the EXAMPLES section of `man find`:

```
find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;
```

It looks to me like the `{}` part needs to be in single quotes.

Comment: The `{}` does not need to be quoted in POSIX sh-style shells.